# Finding word similarities along the output or input vectors using gensim word2vec?

Tags: word2vec

I know that you can use model.wv.most_similar(...) to get words by cosine similarity in gensim.

I also know gensim gives you input and output vectors in e.g. model.syn0 and model.syn1neg.

Is there a simple way to calculate cosine similarity and create a list of most similar using **only** the input or output vectors, one or the other? E.g. I want to try doing it using **just** output vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in facility, but I believe you could achieve it by creating a separate `KeyedVectors` instance where you replace the usual ('input projection'/'syn0') vector-array with the same-sized output array (as exists in negative-sampling models).

Roughly the following may work:

```py
full_w2v_model = ... # whatever training/loading is necessary
full_w2v_model.wv.save_word2vec_format(PATH)  # saves just the word-vectors
out_vecs = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(PATH)  # reloads as separate object
out_vecs.vectors = full_w2v_model.syn1neg  # clobber raw vecs with model's output layer
```

(Let me know if this works as-is or neds some further touch-up to work!)

Comment: Terrific! This worked perfectly without any further changes. Thank you very much!